# Как заменить фрагмент текста в CLOB?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, xml

Вопрос в следующем. 
Нужно заменить вот такие фрагменты

```xml
    <ProductStatusCode></ProductStatusCode>
      <DateFrom></DateFrom>
      <SERVICE_CODE>P12345</SERVICE_CODE>
    </P12345>
```

на

```xml
    <ProductStatusCode>DISABLE</ProductStatusCode>
      <DateFrom></DateFrom>
      <SERVICE_CODE>P12345</SERVICE_CODE>
    </P12345>
```

Где **DISABLE** и **P12345** - могут быть разные значения.
Поэтому, думаю, можно вместо них подставить предварительно заведённые переменные в виде *'|| v_product_code ||'*?
А вот что касается тегов DateFrom, то там может быть как пусто (как в данном примере), так и быть какое-то значение. Можно ли как-то с помощью replace или replace_regexp всё это описать?

На данный момент имею вот такое, но как быть с DateFrom, пока не могу разобраться:

```sql
    update variable p
        set v.blob_val = core_gzip.gzip_clob(replace(
    core_gzip.gunzip_to_clob(p_blob => v.blob_val),

                    '<ProductStatusCode></ProductStatusCode>
                    <DateFrom></DateFrom>
                    <SERVICE_CODE>'|| v_product_code ||'</SERVICE_CODE>
                  </'|| v_product_code ||'>',

                    '<ProductStatusCode>'|| v_ProductStatusCodeM_RL ||'</ProductStatusCode>
                    <DateFrom></DateFrom>
                    <SERVICE_CODE>'|| v_product_code ||'</SERVICE_CODE>
                  </'|| v_product_code ||'>'
        )
        where ...
```

Comment: Если это фрагмент xml, то он не валидный, нет окрывающего тега <P12345>

Comment: Открывающий тег есть ранее, просто для replace'а мне достаточно именно этого фрагмента.

Comment: Я понимаю, что он есть ранее. На сколько ранее? Возможно, к нему тоже можно было бы привязаться?

Comment: Сильно раньше, там на 24 строки выше, и много параметров, где также могут быть разные значения, как в случае с datefrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код должен быть примерно таким:

```
update variable p
    set v.blob_val = core_gzip.gzip_clob(regexp_replace(
core_gzip.gunzip_to_clob(p_blob => v.blob_val),
  '(<ProductStatusCode>)(</ProductStatusCode>(\s|\t|\n|\t)*' || 
  '<DateFrom>.*</DateFrom>(\s|\t|\n|\t)*' ||
  '<SERVICE_CODE>'|| v_product_code ||'</SERVICE_CODE>(\s|\t|\n|\t)*' ||
  '</'|| v_product_code  || '>)', 
  '\1' || v_ProductStatusCodeM_RL  || '\2', 
  1, 1, 'i')
    )
    where ...
```

Регулярку разбил на строки, чтобы было проще читать. Выражение между тегами `<DateFrom>/DateFrom>` лучше уточнить, сейчас там просто любые символы.

Немного теории `regexp_replace`: регулярное выражение разбивается на группы скобками. Затем в строке замены указываются группы `\<N>` и дополнительные символы при необходимости.

Работа с регулярными выражениями очень медленная, поэтому я бы не рекомендовал такой подход при больших объемах и частом использовании.

В Oracle есть штатные средства для работы с XML, это будет работать быстрее.